# Team Foundation and Nuget authentication conflict behind proxy

Tags: authentication, tfs, visual-studio-2013, nuget

Recently I'm using TFS behind proxy authentication, everything works well till I try to install packages through the ***Package Manager Console***, if I try to install a package, even if I set up proxy credentials to access TFS, the system asks for credentials to connect to nuget.org, when I input credentials, the authentication through nuget breaks the previous TFS proxy authentication, so I get the error `HTTP code 407: Proxy Athentication Required (Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. )`

After that I can't use nuget and can't use TFS so I have to restart VS2013, but in this way I can't install packages.
Any Idea??

Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the same issue, I can't seem to get nuget packages online

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue with NuGet 2.8.50926.663 and a very restrictive company proxy by installing Fiddler2 from www.fiddlertool.com. It seems having some kind of proxy go-between helps NuGet play nicely with proxies.

Of course there are other tools which will achieve the same effect, e.g. WireShark or Privoxy. I know Fiddler is very useful on a development workstation, so I choose that.

Searching for other solutions kept coming back to issues and regressions of issues in older versions of NuGet, like version 1.5 for example. Seems like either the proxy authentication or HTTPS certificate handling of NuGet is not so streamlined.